# strtok in C and passing arguments

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, strtok

I've got a function whose purpose is to recieve an array of numbers separated by spaces, and one number at a time, assign them to a variable of a struct like this:

```
typedef struct coo {
    int x;
    int y;
} Coord;

typedef struct exer {
    Coord coords[1000];
} exercise;


int coordinates(char *sent){
    char * pal;
    int k=0;
    pal = strtok (sent," ");
    while (pal != NULL)
    {
        exercise.coords[k].x=*pal;
        pal = strtok (NULL," ");
        exercise.coords[k].y=*pal;
        pal = strtok (NULL," ");
        k++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The problem is that the coords that are printed later aren't the same as the given in the sent.

If I input coordinates 1 2 3 4 5 6, it will give me the coordinates 49 50 51 52 53.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: I'm dumber than a mule... Thank you sir.

Comment: @Armin http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC

Answer (score 6):

It's because you get the value of the first *character*. The value `49` you get is the ASCII value for the character `'1'`.

You must convert the string to a number, with e.g. [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

Comment: Give me two valid reasons I shouldn't use `0x30` in place of `'0'`, and one of those reasons will contradict the use and necessity of "ASCII" in this statement. If that term weren't used to describe *character values*, there would be far less encouragement to do *the wrong thing*.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue The OP want normal integer values not strings, so the encoding doesn't really matter (it just happens to be ASCII) just the conversion to integers.

Comment: If the encoding is irrelevant or unimportant, then why mention the encoding? Why not mention that it's a *character value*, instead?

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating upon Joachim Pileborg's answer, `pal` is a pointer to a character. `*pal` is a `char`, which is an integer value representing the character that pal points to. *char*, is the smallest addressable type of integer.

If you're going to use strtol, it'd be wisest to change your `coords` to `long`, so that the types match. The upside is that strtok is pretty lousy at this kind of parsing, and you can completely ditch it.

```
typedef struct {
    long x;
    long y;
} Coord;

/* returns the number of coordinates read. */
size_t read_coordinates(char *str, Coord destination[], size_t capacity);

int main(void) {
    #define EXERCISE_CAPACITY 1000
    Coord exercise[EXERCISE_CAPACITY];
    size_t count = read_coordinates("1 2 3 4 5 6", exercise, EXERCISE_CAPACITY);
}

size_t read_coordinates(char *str, Coord destination[], size_t capacity) {
    size_t x;
    for (x = 0; x < capacity; x++) {
        char *endptr = NULL;
        destination[x].x=strtol(str, &endptr, 10);
        if (endptr - str == 0) {
            // Stop when strtol says it can't process any more...
            break;
        }
        str = endptr + 1;

        destination[x].y=strtol(str, &endptr, 10);
        if (endptr - str == 0) { break; }
        str = endptr + 1;
    }
    return x;
}
```

If you must use `int` as the type for your coords, it would be wise to use sscanf, somewhat like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} Coord;

/* returns the number of coordinates read. */
size_t read_coordinates(char *str, Coord destination[], size_t capacity);

int main(void) {
    #define EXERCISE_CAPACITY 1000
    Coord exercise[EXERCISE_CAPACITY];
    size_t count = read_coordinates("1 2 3 4 5 6", exercise, EXERCISE_CAPACITY);
}

size_t read_coordinates(char *str, Coord destination[], size_t capacity) {
    size_t x;
    for (x = 0; x < capacity; x++) {
        int n;
        if (sscanf(str, "%d %d%n", &destination[x].x, &destination[x].y, &n) != 2) {
            // Stop when sscanf says it can't process any more...
            break;
        }
        str += n;
    }
    return x;
}
```